# How to customize window and panel shadow in KDE

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, kde, themes, shadow

I am satisfying with my theme, but I need to change the color of shadows for windows and panels. I tried to search for it in the settings and Kvantum but with no success.

The theme use `Kvantum` manager.

```
saidbakr@Satellite-L850-A700 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ---------------------------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: Satellite L850-A700 PSKDLV-03C 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.0.0-37-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 3 hours, 39 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 3447 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 4.4.20 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1440x900 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: KDE 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: KWin 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: Layan 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Layan [KDE], Layan-dark [GTK3 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: Tela-dark [KDE], Tela-dark [G 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: terminator 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: Intel i5-2450M (4) @ 3.100GHz 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: AMD Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Serie 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         Memory: 2909MiB / 7933MiB 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:` 
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```

Answer (score 0):

System Settings/Application Style/Window Decorations will display your currently-selected theme. On each theme display there is a button (on mine it is a spanner but I've got a feeling that is itself theme-dependent). Click on the button and you get a window with tabs, one of which is labelled Shadows, from which you can change the thickness and color, although that might be theme-dependent too (I have Breeze selected at that point but my setup uses a bit of a mish-mash of things from various themes.)

Comment: Unfortunately, this option is available  only for Breeze, but it is not available for any other theme. Other themes have only one default tab that only allows choose  window top buttons size.